# IRequestChannel request is slow

Tags: c#, wcf, compact-framework

I am calling a simple helloworld webservice from a mobile device windows mobile 6. I measured everything and everything is fast except this

```
 return requestChannel.Request(msg);
```

This is slow.. I takes 300 - 380 ms!! Does anybody have an idea why this is so slow... XML desirialization/serialization is way faster than this..

Comment: At 300 milliseconds, hell is looking a lot faster than some Math lectures I've attended.

Comment: Ok.. I think that the problem is with DNS lookup.. Tried with simple sockets and i needed too much time!Then i used IPAdress.Parse and took only 8 ms! However i dont know how to apply this to the webservice as it accepts only url

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a WCF expert by any means, but if I'm not mistaken the `Request` method actually sends a request over the network, right?

Sending and receiving data over the network is about the slowest thing you can do in a computer program (short of asking the user for input, anyway). On a mobile device, speeds are likely to be even worse. I'd bet you're spending 99% of your time waiting for the request/response to complete and 1% of the time actually processing the response.

Short of improving the wireless data infrastructure in your client's city, the only thing you can really do to prevent this is to reduce the number of requests you make to services.